# How to bind selected value of a DropDownListFor to selectedId property in viewmodel, when selected value of DropDownListFor is changed by Jquery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, mvvm, binding, dropdownlistfor

I have two addresses Mailing and Business on UI, and I am implementing 'Same as above' checkbox where user selects this checkbox and Business address below will be populated with above mailing address using Jquery. I am using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` for States.

For this UI I have a ViewModel which has `int selectedBusinessId {get; set;}` property which is set as [Required].

When user manually changes dropdown value, DropDownListFor binds the selected value to the above viewmodel property, no issue here. So when user selects 'Same as above' checkbox, the Business Address State dropdown gets set to Mailing Address State USING Jquery, BUT the issue is on submit it throws model error that State is Required.

**So how to bind selected value of DropDown to viewmodel int selectedBusinessId when DropDownListFor selected value is changed by jquery?**

**ViewModel Class**

```
 public class ContactInformationViewModel
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
        public string mailingAddrSelectedState_Id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> states {get; set;}
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
        public string businessAddrSelectedState_Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
        public string faaAddrSelectedState_Id { get; set; }
    }
```

**UI**

Mailing Address State dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.mailingAddrSelectedState_Id, Model.states, "-- Select --", new { tabindex = 6 })
```

Business Address State dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.businessAddrSelectedState_Id, Model.states, "-- Select --", new { tabindex = 14 })
```

So when user selects 'Same as above' checkbox I am selecting Business Address State as Mailing's State using jquery, but I think I also need to bind the selected Business Address State to businessAddrSelectedState_Id in ViewModel so that on Submit it will have the selected State.

**JQuery**

```
 $('#Same_as_above').change(function(){
        if (this.checked == true)
        {
            var mail_state = $('#mailingAddrSelectedState_Id :selected').val();
            $('#businessAddrSelectedState_Id').val(mail_state);
            $("#businessAddrSelectedState_Id").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you done so far? Post some code!

Comment: Here's some code, thanks Michael

Comment: "....to Mailing Address State USING Jquery" Using Jquery how ? Show us your code.

Comment: Here's jquery code, thanks TCHdvlp

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. Model was not able to bind it since I was disabling Business Address State dropdown in jquery. I commented that and ran smoothly. I think instead of disabling I will make it readonly.

```
 $('#Same_as_above').change(function(){
    if (this.checked == true)
    {
        var mail_state = $('#mailingAddrSelectedState_Id :selected').val();
        $('#businessAddrSelectedState_Id').val(mail_state);
     // $("#businessAddrSelectedState_Id").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
```

Thank you all for taking time to review my issue, I appreciate.